# How to separate code (clean code separation) in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I just want to know now how to separate code in proper way in MVC3 using EF

As per my project structure.

Presentation -> View & Controller

Domain --> Model (Business Entity)

Data --> RepositoryBase, IRepository, ApplicationDbContext

Services --> 3rd Party Service (PayPal, SMS) or Application Service

ApplicationDbContext require Model as reference.

```
public sealed class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<CountryModel> Country { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

**1. So is it good to place DbContext in Data ? Or I have to move it into Domain ?**

Now in Controller I have to write a code

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var countryRepository = new Repository<Country>(db);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        countryRepository.insert(country);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to Separate this code block any Business Layer / Service Layer ?

So we just Call that Layer from controller & just pass the Specific Business Entity in order to perform rest of the operation.

I want to do PL --> BLL --> DLL approach Using MVC 3 & EF ?

Please suggest me the proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is it good to place DbContext in Data ?

Yes, it's where it belongs.

> Now in Controller I have to write a code

No, you absolutely should not write code like this in the controller because you are now making your controller strongly coupled to the specific data access technology you are using (EF in your case). Even worse you will not be able to unit test your controllers in isolation.

I would recommend you abstracting the operations over the entities in an interface (you already have mentioned it by the way in your question - `IRepository`). And now your controller could take the repository as dependency:

```
public class CountriesController: Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    public CountriesController(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        Country country = this.repository.Get<Country>(id);
        return View(country);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Country country)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.repository.Insert(country); 
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }

        return View(country);
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is configure your favorite dependency injection framework to inject the specific implementation of this IRepository into the controller constructor. In your case this specific implementation could be some class that implements the IRepository interface and which is using the `ApplicationDbContext` inside.

This way you are abstracting away the data access logic from your controllers.

Comment: Greate, But If I have multiple interface then what should I do ? Let Say ** CountryRepository: IRepository, ICountryRepository ** then in **CountryController(IRepository, ICountryRepository)** I have to write this way ? And within **CountryRepository** I have to write **ApplicationDbContext** related code ?

Comment: IRepository could be generic as shown in my example: `IRepository<T>`. So your `CountryRepository` could implement `IRepository<Country>` and then your controller will take `IRepository<Country>`. It's all you need. Now inside the `CountryRepository` implementation you could work with the `ApplicationDbContext`.

Comment: For example in the Get method of `CountryRepository`: `using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext()) { return db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryId == id); }`

Comment: can give example of code **ApplicationDbContext** with **RepositoryBase** or in **CountryRepository** ? If I have to implement Another **ICountryInterface** within **CountryRepository** So within **CountryController** I have to Pass IReposotory And ICountryReposotory Right !!!

Comment: No, you don't need to pass any `ICountryRepository` to the controller. There's no such interface. All your controller needs is a `IRepository<Country>`. And your `CountryRepository` class implements `IRepository<Country>`. If your controller needs to work with other models, you simply pass their repositories as well: `IRepository<Product>`, `IRepository<FooBar>`, ...

Comment: IF I required a Country Specific Operation which is not available within **IRepository** then What should I Do ? I have to implement another interface for **CountryRepository** , I am asking abount that case  ??

Comment: You could define a service. That could be your business layer. The service will then depend on the country repository.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213294/please-help-is-bellow-code-clean-code-separation-correct-mvc-3-ef) as per your standard approach is right ?

Answer (score 2):

u can make separate project for each other in BLL create class for each business entity call repository form there and create some basic function that u need to there like insert delete find select with parameter etc

```
var country =new Country();//it's class of BLL

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    country.insert(country);
}
```

something like that